# pass list of elements inside cursor.execute mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a list of multiple elements as :

```
l=['asia','america','africa','australia'].
```

I have mysql table and all I want to count a occurance of word within all rows of column so for example if `asia` is a word of which I want to check count then I used:

`cursor.execute("select count(*)from table_text where round(match(text) against('asia'),5)")
cursor.fetchall()`

and I got count as `48`. How I can pass all list elements as parameter inside `cursor.execute` and get all words count simultaneously?
I did something as:-

```
for i in l:
    cursor.execute("select count(*)from table_text where round(match(text) against('"i"'),5)")
    cursor.fetchall()
```

That gives an error!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `+` operator for string. So, you can do something like:-

```
list_new=[]
for words in l:
    cursor.execute("select count(*)from table_text where round(match(text) against('"+words+"'),5)")
    tagg=cursor.fetchall()
    for i in tagg[0]:
        list_new.append(i)
print (list_new)     #Gives you list of counts of all elements
```

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: I guess you've never heard of [sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). Consider what would happen if someone passed in `words = "blah'),5); drop table table_text; --"`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do with the query. I see a few mistakes:

```
select count(*)from table_text where round(match(text) against('"i"'),5)
```

- Firstly add a space between count and from
- Secondly the condition 'match(text) against('"i"')' makes sense but what is the purpose of the round function?
- Finally, with an aggregate function such as count, you need a groupby at the end.

I think you can use spaces in your condition to match one of the words. Something like:

```
conditions = '"' + ' '.join(l) + '"'
# conditions = '"asia america africa australia"'

query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM table_text WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST(' + conditions + ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)'
```

Also be careful with quotes and double quotes. The elements of l have simple quotes whereas your query uses double quotes.

Comment: what is use of  `' " '` in `conditions` variable?

Comment: GROUP BY is not required. If using aggregates without one, then it is as if `GROUP BY ()` was added. There's no need to be careful with quoting, if passing values is done *right*, i.e. using placeholders. String concatenating values to a query is both error prone, as you hint, and dangerous. Documentation on fulltext search also doesn't seem to mention `|` as a valid operator (or I looked in the wrong place). Just white space separated words implies "or".

Comment: Because you want '... AGAINST("asia | america | africa | australia") ... ' as you use simple quotes for the query, and AGAINST requires a string so the only possibility is "asia | america | africa | australia", not asia ... australia without quotes  or 'asia... australia' as it would conflit with the rest of the query.

Comment: ...Also any special operators work only in [boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you for your corrections, I edited my answer accordingly. However, I think we still need a GROUP BY, otherwise the count would be done with every text containing one of the elements, and I think the author wants the count to be done by element... Am I right ?

Comment: I'd say you are, but there's a problem: what would you group by? I suppose the text being matched against is fairly unique per row, so grouping by it  would produce a lot of counts of 1. This'd be easier if MySQL allowed any old expression in `AGAINST`, but alas it does not – only constant string expressions are allowed, so you cannot for example join against a derived table of words to look for and then group by word. I wonder if there's some function or operator that allows peeking what exactly matched. That'd be a good candidate for grouping.

Comment: How about the ['regexp_substr'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr)  function?
The query would become:
'SELECT count(*), REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, conditions) as country FROM table_text GROUP BY country'